# jquery click to set background color of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In coding , I want to create jQuery function, work like this

First `<li>` have `background : red;`

When I click link `<a href="JavaScript:doCallAjax('Good');"> Good</a>` , it's will be set this `<li>` style to `background : red;` and set other `<li>` to `background : none;`

OR

When I click link `<a href="JavaScript:doCallAjax('Normal');"> Normal</a>` , it's will be set this `<li>` style to `background : red;` and set other `<li>` to `background : none;`
too.

```
<ul class="item">
  <li class="item_list" style=" border-right: 2px solid #e6e6e6;  float: left;  margin: 0 0 3px;  padding: 0 5px; background: red; ">
    <a href="JavaScript:doCallAjax('');">All</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item_list" style=" border-right: 2px solid #e6e6e6;  float: left;  margin: 0 0 3px;  padding: 0 5px; ">
    <a href="JavaScript:doCallAjax('Good');"> Good</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item_list" style=" border-right: 2px solid #e6e6e6;  float: left;  margin: 0 0 3px;  padding: 0 5px; ">
    <a href="JavaScript:doCallAjax('Normal');"> Normal</a><br>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I do ?  Thank you for every ans

Answer (score 0):

On click of anchor, you can set all list items background to none and then change only the background color to red using **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** for the targeted parent list item of your clicked anchor using **[.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)**:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $('ul li').css('background','none');
    $(this).parent().css('background','red');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V9b92/1/)**

---

Based on your comment, you can use `.` to target elements by class:

```
$('ul.item li.item_list a').click(function() {
    $('ul.item li.item_list').css('background','none');
    $(this).parent().css('background','red');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V9b92/2/)**

Comment: How can i use class name in this code

`$('ul class="item" li class="item_list"').click(function() {
    $('ul class="item" li class="item_list"').css('background','none');
    $(this).css('background','red');
});`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet

```
 <a href="JavaScript:doCallAjax('Good');" onclick="$(this).parent().css( 'background', 'none');"> Good</a>
```

For more
http://api.jquery.com/css/ & 
https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li style=" border-right: 2px solid #e6e6e6;  float: left;  margin: 0 0 3px;  padding: 0     5px; background: red; ">
     <a href="JavaScript:doCallAjax('');">All</a>
  </li>
  <li style=" border-right: 2px solid #e6e6e6;  float: left;  margin: 0 0 3px;  padding: 0 5px; ">
   <a id="redColor" href="#"> Good</a>
</li>
  <li style=" border-right: 2px solid #e6e6e6;  float: left;  margin: 0 0 3px;  padding: 0 5px; ">
    <a id="notRed" href="#"> Normal</a><br>
  </li>
</ul> 

 <script type=text/javascript>
  $("#redColor").click(function(){
      $(li).css("background-color","red");
   });

  $("#notRed").click(function(){
    $(li).css("background-color","none");
  });
 </script>
```